# Android 5 how to style Overflow Menu

Tags: android, overflow, styling

I have just got the last Android 5 on my tablet(yeah finally, NZ is the end of the world for updates) and now I'm updating my Apps for the new OS.

How to style the OverFlow Menu?
I would have thought that it would be done very easily with some new Android 5 code but havent found so far!
And the "old" way (below), doesn't seem to work

Could someone help please?

```
<item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/ActionBarWidget</item>

<!-- OVERFLOW MENU -->
<style name="ActionBarWidget" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_title</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/main_accent</item>
</style>
```